# OpenDolphin, Spring and MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, opendolphin

Is it posible to use OpenDolphin with Spring as server-side framework and MongoDB as database ?
I want to build simple team application that demonstrates capabilities of team collaboration. I am intrested in advice for techonology to use.

Answer (score 0):

yes this is possible.

for a start, try to use spring-boot and there the spring-boot-starter-web artefact. then extend the DolphinServlet and register that servlet with the help of a ServletRegistrationBean. after you registered an action you might connect to a MongoDB database as you do with any java application.

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(serverServlet, "/s");
    return registrationBean;
}
```

the open dolphin jumpstart project is a good starting-point:
https://github.com/canoo/DolphinJumpStart

Comment: @Sysrq147 have you been successful with a spring & OpenDolphin so far ?